# The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file

Tags: apt, docker

I've installed Docker for Debian following the [official installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/). My `/etc/apt/sources.list` now contain this line:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
```

However, when running `apt-get update`, I get an `The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file` error message:

```
root@server:~# apt-get update
Ign:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease
Err:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch Release      
  Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
<snip>
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

[The Docker apt repo](https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/) does seems to contain the Release file. What am I missing here, what's causing apt to state that there's no release file in the repo?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133455/docker-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file-on-running-apt-get-update-on-ubun/43639310

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker repository does indeed have a [`Release` file](https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/Release) for Stretch, but your proxy is denying access to it:

```
Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

[HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) is the “Forbidden” status, *i.e.* your client is not allowed, by the proxy, to access the target URL.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not about this case, but whoever searches for it: I had a similar issue where for https_proxy I made a typo and I typed the proxy URL with https://... and it did not work with our company proxy (only http://... works). It took some time to realize the problem, because the real cause of the problem is "hidden" earlier in the output and not printed as long and as spectacularly and because of the misleading/inaccurate error message is at the end, quite long, so catches the attention more.